# PHP mail() function - "from" name overwritten by Exchange Server

Tags: php, email, exchange, smtp

I originally posted this on stack overflow but was told it might be better placed here on Serverfault.

I am trying to send a very simple email from a php script

```
 mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
```

Where `$headers` is:

```
$headers = "From: Toms Script <noreply@domain.com>\n\r";
```

The problem I seem to be experiencing is that when the email hits our Exchange server to send, it recognises we have the email address of "*noreply*" saved under the name of "System Notificatons" and sends the email from that name instead of the name defined in my PHP script (Toms Script).

Is there anyway to stop **Microsoft Exchange** making this change so we can name different emails from different scripts accordingly, but still send from the "noreply" email address?